How to create SpotBugs report with Gradle?
I don't know how to create reports with SpotBugs in my Gradle config.
Here's my config (non-SpotBugs stuff ommitted):
import com.github.spotbugs.snom.Confidence
import com.github.spotbugs.snom.Effort

plugins {
    id("com.github.spotbugs") version "6.0.16"
}

spotbugs {
    ignoreFailures = true
    showStackTraces = true
    showProgress = true
    effort = Effort.MAX
    reportLevel = Confidence.LOW
    reportsDir = file("${layout.buildDirectory}/reports/spotbugs")
}

This way, I get two files spotbugsMain-analyse-class-file.txt and spotbugsTest-analyse-class-file.txt, plus a spotbugs directory containing an auxclasspath directory, but everything is in the build directory (not in that directory's reports subdirectory, where the reports of Checkstyle and PMD end up without any additional config).
Any idea?
